# Redirect bash variable into netcat

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, variable

I am attempting to write a bash loop that passes a bash string into netcat. The command that I execute is:

```
nc -nv [ipaddress] [port] << EOF
10000
EOF
```

I am writing a bash loop to perform this and I've tried a number of options. Here's the basic one I've tried that doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare number
COUNTER=0
END=$(bc <<< -2^10)
while [ $COUNTER -gt $END ]; do
        nc -nv [IPADDRESS] [PORT] << $COUNTER
        let COUNTER=COUNTER-1
done
```

Comment: The `<<` operator takes a string and then reads everything until it finds that string again.  You need `<<EOF\n$COUNTER\nEOF`.

Comment: Since you appear to want to send only a single value, why not use a *here string* `<<< "$COUNTER"` rather than trying to use a here document?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to grochmal and steeldriver for the ideas. The answer was to use <<<

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare number
COUNTER=0
END=$(bc <<< -2^10)
while [ $COUNTER -gt $END ]; do
    nc -nv [IPADDRESS] [PORT] <<< $COUNTER
    let COUNTER=COUNTER-1
done
```

If you want more information about here strings it can be found at: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html